# How do i get the tables to seperate

Tags: html, css

Okay, so I am trying to seperate these tables. At first I thought they would just go apart. But everytime i try anything it will just not work

```
 <div class="box">

<!-- POST ICON AND DATE -->
<div class="left">
<p>Blank text</p>
</div>

<!-- POST TEXT -->
<div class="right">
<p><b>Blank text</b><br>
hbugyuoygouyguyguyg</p>
</div>    
<!-- POST END--> 
<!-- post start -->
<div class="box">

<div class="left">
<p>Blank text</p>
</div>

<!-- POST TEXT -->
<div class="right">
<p><b>Blank text</b><br>
jhbjhbjv</p>
```

this is what i did and everything is fine except the tables are right next to each other one is supposed to be under the other.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example in particular we can’t experience your problem because there is no CSS shown.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can not see your CSS but there is a problem with your html arrangement.

You have some missing closing  tags.

The first parent class is missing a closing tag so as the secound one.

Try this:

```
<div class="box">

<!-- POST ICON AND DATE -->
<div class="left">
<p>Blank text</p>
</div>

<!-- POST TEXT -->
<div class="right">
<p><b>Blank text</b><br>
hbugyuoygouyguyguyg</p>
</div>  
</div> <!-- There should be a closing tag here-->  
<!-- POST END--> 
<!-- post start -->
<div class="box">

<div class="left">
<p>Blank text</p>
</div>

<!-- POST TEXT -->
<div class="right">
<p><b>Blank text</b><br>
jhbjhbjv</p>
</div>

</div> <!-- There should be a closing tag here-->
```